# How to send a file to MVC action using only one submit button

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to open the OpenFileDialog using js then grab the selected file using only a submit button (without using a form)

this is what i have so far.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadAttachment", "DMS", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input  type="file" name="attach" />
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="attach">Upload</button>
}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UploadAttachment(HttpPostedFileBase attach)
{
    // file processing
}
```

Comment: is your question meaningful. please read it once and rephrase it.

Comment: Ok, I want a single button on my page that opens the OpenFileDialog and then after the user selects a file, I want to be able to process the file in an MVC controller.

Comment: you want to pass the file to the controller without using a form ? please clarify your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm interpreting your question a little.. I will make two assumptions:

1) you want to upload a file without posting a form and so refreshing the page ie asynchronous upload
2) you want to be able to launch the picker with any button you like (so you can style it how you want to)

The solution below will launch a file picker when a button is clicked. Multiple files can be selected and they will be posted to the server asynchronously (AJAX).

```
<input type="file" name="attach" id="attach-input" multiple="" style="display:none" />
<button type="submit" name="attach" id="attach-button">Upload</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var button = $('#attach-button');
    var input = $('#attach-input');

    // translates collection of files into a form
    function BuildFormData(files) {

        var data = new FormData();

        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

            data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
        }

        return data;
    }

    // posts the files to a given url
    function PostData(url, data) {

        $.ajax({
            // method
            type: 'POST',

            // endpoint
            url: url,

            // next 2 lines required for using FormData with jQuery
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,

            // FormData instance
            data: data,

            // success handler
            success: function (result) {

                alert('files uploaded successfully');

                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    }

    // when the button is clicked..
    button.on('click', function (e) {

        // it launches the file picker
        input.click();
    });

    // when the file picker changes..
    input.on('change', function (e) {

        // turn it into a form
        var data = BuildFormData(e.target.files);

        // post the form to the action method
        PostData('/Index/Attach', data);
    });

</script>
```

The action method I used in the asp.net MVC controller will save the files to the App_Data folder of the application:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Attach()
    {
        foreach (string file in Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase fileContent = Request.Files[file];

            Stream stream = fileContent.InputStream;

            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);

            string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);

            using(var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(path))
            {
                stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope that steers you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you so much <3
note: you might wanna change  PostData('/Index/Attach', data); to  PostData('/Home/Attach', data); or even  PostData('/{controller}/{action}', data); unless you have a controller named Index :P
Again, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Ha - yeah actually that's what my controller was called. Nice idea to let the view populate it automatically though, I like that.